# chsh: PAM authentication failed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i want to change default shell env

and run `chsh -s /bin/zsh` as root user,

but a error message appeared: `chsh: PAM authentication failed`.

i find this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1702833

but the answer did not solve my problem

any help would be appreciated

---

this is the content of /etc/pam.d/chsh

```
#
# The PAM configuration file for the Shadow `chsh' service
#

# This will not allow a user to change their shell unless
# their current one is listed in /etc/shells. This keeps
# accounts with special shells from changing them.
auth       required   pam_shells.so

# This allows root to change user shell without being
# prompted for a password
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so

# The standard Unix authentication modules, used with
# NIS (man nsswitch) as well as normal /etc/passwd and
# /etc/shadow entries.
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

this is the content of /etc/shells

```
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/tmux
/usr/bin/screen
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

---

i find that i used to run `chsh -s zsh`
this will change first line of `/etc/passwd` as

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:zsh
```

and `chsh` will ask for password whaterver you try

i just edit `/etc/passwd` file manually, and everything is ok.

stupid mistake and thanks for your replies

Comment: Can you provide your /etc/pam.d/chsh ? (BTW it's generally considered a good idea for the root login shell to be minimal / stable - is there areason you want zsh as the default shell rather than starting it after login?)

Comment: i just want to auto-enter zsh shell when i was just logged in, maybe this is not good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your /etc/shells file and add /bin/zsh to file if this line does not exists.

Comment: this answer inspired me to check `/etc/passwd` file whether i input the correct format of shell name. Thx

Comment: For me, using a vagrant VM, I needed to change `/etc/passwd`.  Thanks @txworking!

Comment: For me, the issue is called by an erroneous configuration for shell inside `/etc/passwd` for the root account...

Answer (score 6):

Check your `/etc/passwd`. In my case I had specified an invalid shell with `chsh` previously and that's what was causing the problem.

I changed it from `zsh` as the shell to `/bin/zsh` and that made the problem go away for me.

Answer (score 4):

You must run your code as sudo:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

I had same problem too, and it worked!

Comment: Won't this change the root user's shell?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem.
whenever i typed in **chsh** it use to prompt

```
chsh: PAM authentication failed
```

But I solved it by doing some modification in the `/etc/passwd` file

```
Users of kali-linux
```

just open your root terminal
and modify `/etc/passwd` file
you can use pico,nano,or vi editor for this job i am going by vi

```
vi /etc/passwd
```

then search for the user account. and change the shells to your desired shell
make sure the desired shell in installed in your distros of linux
for new user to see what shells are present in their linux just type in

```
cat /etc/shells
```

it lists them there .If at all you have install the shell and you are unable to see it in `/etc/shell` you need to create a link and place path of shell say for suppose `/bin/ksh` in `/etc/shells` file manually...

for example you are in bash and you want to change it to ksh

just go to account in `/etc/passwd` file and in the last field edit

`/bin/bash` to `/bin/ksh` or `/bin/ksh93` (as in your `cat /etc/shells`)

just logout and login and you are good to go...

for users of other distros (say) ubuntu

type in

`sudo -H gnome-terminal` (to get a root terminal)

and the process is same as above as you too have root terminal like a kali-linux user..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your path my be wrong.  To check it:

```
[nick ~]$ which zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

If the result is /usr/bin/zch, this should do the trick:

```
[nick ~]$ chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```

*edit for typo.